# Distcc refuses to compile with arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: gcc

I have distcc 3.3.3 (Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.4.0, both x86) on both the server and the client. Setup correctly, as far as I can tell, because it works when compiling for the x86 architecture with gcc. Invoking the make command from the client with `make -j8 CC='distcc arm-none-eabi-gcc'` results in distcc choosing to execute on localhost instead of the server. It successfully detects the host from the config, acquires the lock but then doesn't output any error and chooses localhost. `arm-none-eabi-gcc` is installed on both, and is the same version: 10.2.1, as well as any other tool that I need. What exactly is the problem here?

More details:

- `arm-none-eabi-gcc` is accessible from anywhere, as it is on the path;
- The libraries needed are not on the server, as per my research, they don't need to be. All the libraries I use are .c or .h files that need to be sent anyway as they need to be compiled.
- config file on the server:

```
STARTDISTCC="true"
ALLOWEDNETS="192.168.100.0/24"
LISTENER="192.168.100.44"
NICE="5"
JOBS=""
ZEROCONF="false"
```

- config on the client: hosts set to `192.168.100.44/6`, no fallback, everything else set to default
- the helper's distcc service is active and working
- pump mode doesn't make any difference
- different j number of jobs given to make doesn't make any difference as well

Comment: Do you have arm libraries and headers on the local machine?

Comment: @Ginnungagap I sure do. I can compile just fine on my local machine, everything works great, it's just very slow as it is an almost 8 year old machine at this point

Comment: Any chance that the libraries you use require a system header and/or library that you're missing on the server?

Comment: At most, I think I use string.h, but that is definitely on the server. What I think I don't have, but I don't think it needs, is the linker script. As far as I understand, distcc doesn't link anything. Anything else is either a header that is included in the source files, and the source files themselves. No precompiled libraries